# Creating multiple varibles by adding numbers in a range to the end

Tags: python, physics

this is my first post on this forum hope your all doing well. im fairly new to python and currently using it to do data analysis for an astronomy project. I have loaded 8 .dat files each containing multiple values of period for each galaxy using numpy.

```
logp1,m_1 =np.loadtxt('hst_gal1_cepheids.dat',\
        unpack=True, \
        usecols=(1,2), \
        dtype=float)
logp2,m_2 =np.loadtxt('hst_gal2_cepheids.dat',\
        unpack=True, \
        usecols=(1,2), \
        dtype=float)`
  `
```

and so on...

I have to use the equation M_(n)=slope*logp(n)+incept(the variables slope and incept have been defined before). I initially did this by

```
M_2=slope*logp2+incpt
M_3=slope*logp3+incpt
```

however this seemed long and messy. i tried using

```
`for i in range(1,8):
 def func(slope,incept,logpi:
          return M_[i]=slope*logp[i]+incpt`
```

to create multiple M varibles from 1 to 8 which would correspond to the correct galaxy however it comes with invalid syntax error after return.
i also tried using the .append

```
M_.append(str[i])=slope*logp.append(i)+incept`
```

but this also gave me an error of "cant assign to function call"
I’m sorry if this seem as very novice code but I’m very new to coding and trying to get the hang of it. 
any sort of help would be appreciated .
much love.

Comment: If you only need 8 variables of M (with a sequential number at the end), why not just create them in the first place? You can store all 8 of them in an array and then use one in each loop of your program.

Comment: The function needs a closing parenthesis before the :. Define the function first using yield instead of return. Then create the for loop calling the function with proper indents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend **using dictionary** structure, like this:

```
M_parameters = {}

for i in range(1,8):
        M_parameters[f"M_{i}"]=slope*logp[i]+incpt
```

And then you can get you parameters from the dict like this:

```
M_parameters[M_1]
```

or

```
M_parameters.get(M_1, None) # Get if exists, if not return None
```

if slope and intercept vary for every M, you can form a list of them:

```
weights = [(slope_1, int_1), ..., (slope_8, int_8)]
```

and then extract them from it in a cycle:

```
for i in range(1,8):
    slope, incpt = weights[i-1]
    M_parameters[f"M_{i}"]=slope*logp[i]+incpt
```

Or, if you don't need them as variables and **the list** will be enough, you can just do it like:

```
M = [slope*logp[i]+incpt for i in range(1,8)]
```

And then call them as:

```
M[0], M[1] e.t.c.
```